# Dark veil when getting up too fast

Tags: neuroscience, eyes, vision

I was asking myself this weird question.

When you get up or stand up too fast, sometimes, you see something like a dark veil, and you aren't able to see anything distinctly for 2 or 3 seconds, then it come back to normal.

Do you know what causes this weird phenomenon (biologically speaking), or am i the only weird person feeling this sometimes?

Comment: If your interest is academic then you may wish to look further into [orthostatic hypotension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthostatic_hypotension). I don't know why this causes visual disturbances however.

Comment: the eyes can lose vision easily when they don't get enough oxygen or are otherwise impaired.  I'm reminded of diabetic retinopathy - temporary eyesight loss happens when blood flow to the eyes are interrupted.  this can be a sign that the cardiovascular system isn't as efficient as it should be!

Comment: »[…] or am i the only weird person feeling this sometimes?« Nope, definitely not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's caused by a sudden shift in the pressure needed to circulate blood to your brain which your body fails to respond to sufficiently quickly. This results in a sudden loss of blood pressure termed [Orthostatic Hypotension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthostatic_hypotension) which, in term, results in a transitory reduction in the blood supply necessary for brain function. You experience a momentary loss of vision for the same reason that you would if someone strangles you.

Comment: wow!! Never knew this exists. Can you add some more references?

Comment: Are other brain functions also affected when this happens?

Comment: Other brain functions may indeed also be affected. Dizziness is another possible effect, as one example.

Comment: I would describe it more as a fading of colors and peripheral vision.